# When writing files, will the encoding used by open ever depend on the string you are writing?

Tags: python, encoding

Every day `fetch_poem()` retrieves a poem. On Mondays the poems come back in English, on Tuesdays; in Danish, on Wednesdays; in Norwegian... and so on.

I write the poems out to a file located at `path` every day:

```py
my_poem = fetch_poem()
with open(path, "w") as f:  # 
    f.write(my_poem)
```

My question is, can the encoding depend on the letters / characters / language in the string? I never explicitly pass the encoding to `open()`.

#### [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) says:

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns), but any text encoding supported by Python can be used.

#### My `locale.getpreferredencoding`

I am on a Windows Server with a Danish Locale. Running `getpreferredencoding()` gives **cp1252**:

```
$ python -c "import locale; print(locale.getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale=True))"
cp1252
```

Does this mean cp1252 is used to encode all my files?

Comment: Possibly, and just in Windows (and on some windows version and on some locations), and for actual version of Python. So: put encoding explicit on `open`: less surprise and it serves also as documentation. [BTW: prefer UTF-8]

Comment: The day a poem with a non-UTF-8 character is fetched, the program will error-out. I could wrap the file-writing in a `try-except UnicodeDecodeError` and attempt to fetch_poem() until a UTF-8 compliant one is fetched. It's just not a very elegant solution. Generally I agree, a "just use X" solution for all cases would be gold.

Comment: UTF-8 encodes Unicode, and so it should have all characters. Windows doesn't support characters outside Unicode, and Python strings should already be unicode. [Note ASCII and Latin1 and all windows codepage are subsets of Unicode) -- else you would have written in a binary file (with `b` flag)

Comment: It depends on what you want to later do with those poems. If you process them with an application that expects a specific encoding, then do use that encoding. BTW. For your question, yes on your system,cp1252 will be used for all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `open()` will use your locale's preferred encoding if you don't spell out an encoding.

The proper fix to support arbitrary languages is to use a Unicode encoding and pass it explicitly.

```py
with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(my_poem)
```

I suggest UTF-8, but if you are a Windows victim, perhaps UTF-16le would also in some sense, uh, make sense. It also depends on what is going to consume this file. On Windows, probably use `utf-8-sig` instead of `utf-8` even though having a BOM in UTF-8 is problematic for other reasons.

One of your comments below the question betrays a misunderstanding of how this works. If `fetch_poem()` returns text, that's just Unicode, and not in any particular encoding. Python 3 completely shields you from this detail for strings in memory; it's when you need to communicate them to the outside world (write to a file, send over the network, etc) that you need for them to be encoded.  Perhaps review Ned Batchelder's *[Pragmatic Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)* for a good introduction.

For what it's worth, code page 1252 supports *most* strings in *most* culturally dominant Western European languages (including Danish and Norwegian, but excluding e.g. Sámi languages and Esperanto) but breaks down if you need unusual diacritics or, of course, non-Latin languages. Unicode elegantly solves all of this and a Unicode serialization format should your preferred encoding for any text files.

Comment: Python 3 doesn't shield you from quirks of Unicode such as different composition forms, for instance. Also, it's not exactly correct to say Unicode is a format for text files – Unicode in itself is just the standard mapping; UTF-8 (and the others, cp1252 included) are encodings for text.

Comment: @AKX It's unclear how these comments pertain to this answer. I don't find a place where I claim Unicode is a format for text files, though I tweaked the final sentence slightly. I don't claim Python shields you from the quirks of Unicode; I'm saying Python shields you from the issue of encoding when you are manipulating strings.

Comment: Yes, the final sentence (conflating formats and encodings) was my issue. It's better now :) Regarding Unicode quirks, just wanted to put that out there.